# How to insert json from API to snowflake database using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, linkedin-api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting data from Linkedin AD API using python.
I get the data as a json string.
How can I insert this json into Snowfalke table with a variant column?
Instead of variant, fields inside "elements" can also be inserted as a normal.
I am new to both json and python so would love to get some help on this.
Here is the sample json string I am getting.

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "dateRange": {
                "start": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 3
                },
                "end": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 3
                }
            },
            "clicks": 11,
            "impressions": 2453,
            "pivotValues": [
                "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:1234567"
            ]
        },
        {
            "dateRange": {
                "start": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 4
                },
                "end": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 4
                }
            },
            "clicks": 4,
            "impressions": 816,
            "pivotValues": [
                "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:1234567"
            ]
        },
        {
            "dateRange": {
                "start": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 7
                },
                "end": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 7
                }
            },
            "clicks": 1,
            "impressions": 629,
            "pivotValues": [
                "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:1234565"
            ]
        },
        {
            "dateRange": {
                "start": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 21
                },
                "end": {
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2019,
                    "day": 21
                }
            },
            "clicks": 3,
            "impressions": 154,
            "pivotValues": [
                "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:1323516"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "count": 10,
        "start": 0,
        "links": []
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably be more specific. Is the entire JSON a string? This is unlikely. Provide a sample of the string or JSON and be more specific about what you want - ambiguity will only lead to your question being ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html) might be helpful here.

In particular:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (myColumn) 
SELECT ('{"key3": "value3", "key4": "value4"}'::VARIANT);
```

Just insert your JSON string in the appropriate place.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example in python of how to insert JSON data:

https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/master/test/test_cursor.py#L456

I imagine you're missing the `parse_json` function from your insert.